# C# suitable type for Geographic data on Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, types, geography, azure-table-storage

I wish to store geographic data in my table on azure, but I'm not sure about what Type to use...
Everyone suggests [Microsoft.SqlServer.Geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) but I don't like the idea of referencing SQL Server dll because of one single type... doesn't c# have a native type for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the System.Data.Spatial namespace which contains the [DBGeography class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) class. Very suitable...